# Laravel 5.2 Ajax POST TokenMismatchException with Valid CSRF Token

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, laravel

I'm having trouble with an AJAX POST request in Laravel 5.2. I'm passing a valid CSRF token in my AJAX request.

Opening and closing the form using [Laravel Collective HTML package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form) form tags, which automatically adds a hidden _token input with the CSRF token. Rendered HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/admin/products/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="product-search-form">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="mOaBxU1sVUsRX1KkuAeVhSDSxj0LKT8DDxl9USQc">

<div>
    <label for="keywords" class="required">Keywords</label>
    <input id="keywords" placeholder="Enter keywords" name="keywords" type="text">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="category" class="required">Category</label>
    <select id="category" name="category">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a category...</option>
        <option value="category-1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="category-2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="category-3">Category 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="search-product-submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Using Fetch API and FormData to do AJAX request:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var searchProductSubmitButton = $("search-product-submit");

function fetchStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
}

function fetchJson(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function searchProducts(evt){
    var keywords = $("keywords").value,
        categorySelect = $("category"),
        category = categorySelect.options[categorySelect.selectedIndex].value,
        csrfToken = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")["csrf-token"].getAttribute("content"),
        productSearchForm = $("product-search-form"),
        formData = new FormData(productSearchForm);

    evt.preventDefault();

    if(keywords !== "" && category !== ""){
        fetch("/admin/products/search", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken
            }
        })
        .then(fetchStatus)
        .then(fetchJson)
        .then(function(products) {
            console.log("The operation was a complete success");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Request failed", error);
        });
    }
}
searchProductSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", searchProducts, false);
searchProductSubmitButton.addEventListener("keypress", searchProducts, false);
```

The CSRF token and form data are in the request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQFECPn7xpptqi076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

mOaBxU1sVUsRX1KkuAeVhSDSxj0LKT8DDxl9USQc
------WebKitFormBoundaryQFECPn7xpptqi076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="keywords"

dsafafa
------WebKitFormBoundaryQFECPn7xpptqi076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"

DVD
------WebKitFormBoundaryQFECPn7xpptqi076--
```

The _token input in the request payload and the x-csrf-token header are the same as the token seen in View Source.

Route is using web middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::post('products/search', [ // == "admin/products/search" with prefix
        'as'   => 'products.search',
        'uses' => 'ProductsController@search'
    ]);
});
```

Controller:

```
public function search(SearchRequest $request){
    Log::info('keywords: ' . $request->keywords);
    Log::info('category: ' . $request->category);

    return response()->json([
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'category' => $request->category
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Were there any requests to your application in between receiving the token and submitting it?

Comment: Nope, I'm on my local development environment and only have the site open in one browser tab.

Comment: Are you sure you are not generating it twice? Once for the form element and once for the meta tag?

Comment: The meta tag and hidden form field are identical.

Comment: Have you tried this:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Yes, I tried getting the CSRF token from the meta tag (but didn't use jQuery).

Comment: Are you using some kind of HTML caching middleware? This could lead to wrong token in the view, whereas the real one is set in the session.

Comment: Nope, not currently doing any caching.

Answer (score 0):

I had these problems sometimes too and fixed it by sending a POST with `_token` instead of putting it in the headers.

Or why don't you serialize the whole form?

Comment: I'm already sending _token with the post. Both show the proper CSRF token. I can try serializing, but you don't need to with the FormData API.

Comment: Well the only thing I can imagine going wrong is that the token in the meta tag is not the same as the one in the form. Try sending the form without the headers

Answer (score 0):

I punted on doing a POST request and I'm doing a GET request with URL parameters:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-ajax-post-tokenmismatchexception-with-valid-csrf-token/replies/135330